# How can we create custom actions in new/edit/display form SharePoint ribbon?

Tags: 2013, ribbon, custom-actions

We are using SharePoint 2013 for intranet portal. Not apps.

We have a document library with documents. On clicking the document we get it opened in a modal popup.

On the ribbon of this display form I want to place a clickable item on the ribbon such that, when we click on it, then I want to redirect to an application page with this doc id.

I would also like to know the number of possible ways to do this and the best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by creating a **CustomAction**.  Specify `Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.DisplayForm"` in order to place a button in Display form. Here is an example:

```
<CustomAction
    Id="ExportVersionHistory.DisplayForm"
    RegistrationType="ContentType"
    RegistrationId="0x01"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.DisplayForm"
    Rights="ViewListItems">
        <CommandUIExtension>
            <CommandUIDefinitions>
                <CommandUIDefinition
                 Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls._children">
                    <Button
                     Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls.ExportVersionHistory"
                     Alt="Export version history of the item to Microsoft Excel."
                     LabelText="Export Version History"
                     Image16by16="/_layouts/15/images/NY.ExportVersionHistory/Excel_Small.png"
                     Image32by32="/_layouts/15/images/NY.ExportVersionHistory/Excel_32.gif"
                     Command="ExportVersionHistory"
                     Sequence="99"
                     TemplateAlias="o1"
                     ToolTipTitle="Export Version History"
                     ToolTipDescription="Export version history of the item to Microsoft Excel."/>
                </CommandUIDefinition>
            </CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIHandlers>
                <CommandUIHandler
                 Command="ExportVersionHistory"
                 CommandAction="~site/_layouts/15/NY.ExportVersionHistory/ExportVersionHistory.aspx?List={ListId}&amp;ID={ItemId}"
                 EnabledScript="javascript:ExportVersionHistoryDisplayFormEnable();"/>
            </CommandUIHandlers>
        </CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
```

Comment: Where is this code written? DispForm.aspx?

Comment: it is written in the element .xml of custom action. You can create the custom action by adding an EmptyElement template in vs2010.